# 2D Curve to poly-lines transformation through triangulation?

Tags: qgis, line, polyline-creation, circle, triangulation-survey

I'd like to understand whether it is possible to change the curve in the picture to a sets of poly-lines through triangulation? and is it possible in QGIS? Otherwise, are there other methods to perform this transformation, theoretically, or practically?

Explanation to be more precise:

- I need the curve to be broken down into sets of lines and/or poly lines.
- It does not matter the that the poly-lines are inside or outside the actual curve.
- I want the area of the quarter to be as close as possible to the area of the new polygon.

[image]